# what is 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL?

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to understand how the range encoder works so i found a java program for range encoder then when i was trying to reverse engineer the code where i came across the value 0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL, i would appreciate if any one can tell why we use this value ?

```
    public class RangeCoder64
     {

    static final protected long Top=1L<<48;
    static final protected long Bottom=1L<<40;
    static final protected long MaxRange=Bottom;

    protected long Low=0;
    protected long Range=0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;

     }
```

Comment: Look into hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: A hexadecimal number, which is too big to fit into an int (which is why it has L at the end).  Why you use it?  No clue - it **really** depends on what the application is doing with those bit values.

Comment: `0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL = 2^56 - 1`

Comment: To write the bottom 56 bits you can write `-1L >>> -56` for the top 56 bits you can write `-1L << -56`

Comment: Other nice example `long value = 0B0_010_0L` :)

Comment: That's a 0FULL long literal.

Answer (score 7):

0x represents the value is hexadecimal.

L indicates the literal is a long value.

Basically it's just a large number. (Decimal value is 72057594037927935)

Answer (score 2):

`0x00FFFFFFFFFFFFFFL` is `0x` + `00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF` + `L`

`0x` denotes hex is used

`00FFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is hex for 72,057,594,037,927,935

`L` means that the value is of size Long -- smaller numbers do not need it (below size requiring Long)

When you see a value that is 1 less than a power of 2, it will be right filled with 1's and therefore in hex will be right filled with `F`s.  Genertally, it will be used as a mask, that mask when `and`ed with a value will keep only the low bits, in this case it will discard the highest byte, and keep the 7 low bytes.

Comment: Other answers looked less like mine when I posted

Answer (score 0):

It would be the value of that range.  It looks like 7 bytes.  So for some reason it is restricting the number.